# Possible (but not serious) glitch in close/reopen

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-reopen

I just had one of my questions closed. (Hey - it happens to everyone) When I clicked on reopen - lo and behold - it worked. I cast a reopen vote!

Is this a glitch? I know we need 4 more votes anyway but still...

And no [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) tag please :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> [image]

Thus saith https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes.

Recall to your mind that thou canst vote but once to reopen and once to close; in truth, were this a bug indeed, 'twould not be so grievous a thing as first appear'd.